# Child gameobject counter rotates when rotating parent in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my first-person controller i have an empty gameobject which contains a camera. I want to rotate the gameobject around the y-axis and the camera around the x-axis seperately but the camera counterrotates.

The Structure of my playerobject is as follows:

PlayerObject

- GameObejct
- - Camera

This is a reduced version of the code im using:

```
public Transform GameObject;
private Camera PlayerCamera;
public Quaternion cam_pan;
public Quaternion cam_tilt;

private void Start()
{
    PlayerCamera= GameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
}

private void Update()
{
    cam_tilt = Quaternion.Euler(cam_tilt.eulerAngles.x - Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0, 0);
    cam_pan = Quaternion.Euler(0, cam_pan.eulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0);

    PlayerCamera.transform.rotation = cam_tilt;
    GameObject.transform.rotation = cam_pan;
}
```

I am relatively new to unity so forgive me if I'm missing the obvious but i haven't found any explanation for this behaviour and I'm really at a loss.

Comment: `transform.rotation` is the world space rotation.  If you want to rotate the camera w/respect to its parent in the heirarchy, set `transform.localRotation` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding Input.GetAxis(“Mouse Y”) and subtracting Input.GetAxis(“Mouse X”) just a note if you have ia child when you rotate the parent you also rotate the child

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what did you exactly want to say. I think this is your problem: the camera rotate around X and Y axis; but you want to rotate it just around X axis.

You are rotating your Gameobject around Y axis. Your camera is a child of your Gameobject. It means you are rotating your camera around Y axis. Again you are rotating your camera around X axis. Then your camera will rotate around Y axis and X axis.

If you want to rotate camera just around X axis, don't make it as a child of the Gameobjet.